# MS Access 2010 - TransferText file name limit

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I useDo.cmd TransferText to import some csv files in to my database though i am running in to some problems.
I get an error popup saying that Access is unable to find the file, the suggestions for the cause are the usual, "file does not exist // contains symbols or punctuation // name is too long"

Experimenting has shown that the issue is the file path being too long, in some cases over 230 characters (the files are saved on a network with a badly optimized hierarchy beyond my control)

I have some some experimenting, and it seems that 208 Characters is the limit for this, the CSV are automatically generated, and the names can be shortened slightly, though that won't always be too much of a help as they still need to be easily identifiable.

Is there a solution which would allow importing files with a path longer than the 208 characters, as insisting that the file names are kept short doesn't seem like the best long term solution.

Thanks for any feedback!

Edit: I currently have the below code.

```
file = "\\Long\File\Path\FileName.txt"
path = Left(file, InStrRev(file, "\"))
newfile = Right(file, Len(file) - InStrRev(file, "\"))

Shell ("subst Z:" & & Chr(34) & path & & Chr(34))
fullpath = "Z:\" & newfile

DoCmd.TransferText TransferType:=acImport, TableName:="tbl_name", FileName:=fullpath, HasFieldNames:=True

Shell ("subst Z: /d")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call good ol' *DOS* command *Subst* before or when running your application:

```
Subst x: f:\some\very\long\path
```

Now x: will have that long path folder as its root.

Then export to drive x:

When finished, call:

```
Subst x: /d
```

to remove drive x:.

Use Shell from inside Access:

```
Shell "Subst x: f:\some\very\long\path"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go.
When we map network drives on our laptops / Desktops, we have to log in in order for the mapping to work.
Will the authorization check cause problems with the command? Will we need to enter the username and password every time?

Comment: No, the neat flip side is that _Subst_ is purely local.

Comment: So assuming i had already mapped the drive, it should be fine?
Next question though, possibly a dumb one... how do i get my software to run this DOS script.
The path is variable depending on the file selected to be importing.
Using VBA I am able to isolate the path, and the file names, so I am able to format the command with every properly, just not sure how to run a create a DOS script and run it through VBA

Comment: You can call an outside process like a DOS command with the `Shell` function. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
I have tried to implement this, and while the subst command appears to be doing something (a window quickly popped up and then disappeared) when reacing the part later where trying to use the new drive we create is coming up with an error "Z:\FileName.txt is not found" etc etc.

Am I making a really stupid mistake / Have i missed something out?
I have made an edit to the question which contains the code.

I have used console output to confirm that the variables are correct.

Comment: Gustav, Is there a way of checking that the subst command has gone through correctly?
Edit :Using cmd prompt it create a virtual drive in "My computer" however the vba script does not, presumably this means the error is there

Comment: There shall be a _space_ between the parameters and _no trailing backslash_ for Subst to work. As in my answer.